# How to generate XMLGregorianCalendar time as UTC

Tags: java, utc, xmlgregoriancalendar

I want to create an `XMLGregorianCalendar` with the following characteristics:

- Time only
- UTC timezone (The "Z" appended at the end)

So I would expect the date to be printed as: **18:00:00Z** ([XML Date](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp)).

The element is an xsd:time and I want the time to be displayed like this in the XML.

```
<time>18:00:00Z</time>
```

But I am getting the following: **21:00:00+0000**. I am at -3 offset and the result is the calculation with my offset.

Why is wrong with my code?

```
protected XMLGregorianCalendar timeUTC() throws Exception {
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ssZZ");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String dateS = df.format(date);
    return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(dateS);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `'Z'` at the end of he pattern will do the job.

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

Answer (score 8):

To get an output you've mentioned (`18:00:00Z`) you have to set the XMLGregorianCalendar's timeZone offset to 0 (`setTimezone(0)`) to have the `Z` appear. You can use the following:

```
protected XMLGregorianCalendar timeUTC() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));

        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(
                dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        xmlcal.setTimezone(0);

        return xmlcal;
    }
```

If you would like to have the full DateTime then:

```
protected XMLGregorianCalendar timeUTC() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(
                (GregorianCalendar)GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
    }
```

The ouput should be something like this: `2017-08-04T08:48:37.124Z`

Comment: I have updated my question, I need the date to be formatted like this `<time>18:00:00Z</time>` in the XML.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it. It works on my side!

Comment: It works! As I am using Java 6 I had to set the timezone like this `TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")`